# CakePHP on production server issues (CentOS)

Tags: php, cakephp, caching

So I just moved my files to a production server (CentOS), where my `DocumentRoot` would be `/srv/www/example.com/app/webroot`. when accessing through a browser I get the following error.

**PS:** I have set `apache` to user group `www-data` and that group is owner of `/home/user/` and its subfolders (containing **CakePHP** core) and also the group is owner of `/srv/www/`.

```
[15-Mar-2014 19:47:46] PHP Warning:  SplFileInfo::openFile(/srv/www/example.com/app/tmp/cache/persistent/myapp_cake_core_file_map) [<a href='function.SplFileInfo-openFile'>function.SplFileInfo-openFile</a>]: failed to open stream: Success in /home/user/cakephp-core/cakephp-2.4.6/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 355

[15-Mar-2014 19:47:46] PHP Warning:  SplFileInfo::openFile(/srv/www/example.com/app/tmp/cache/persistent/myapp_cake_core_cake_dev_en-us) [<a href='function.SplFileInfo-openFile'>function.SplFileInfo-openFile</a>]: failed to open stream: Success in /home/user/cakephp-core/cakephp-2.4.6/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 355

[15-Mar-2014 19:47:46] PHP Warning:  _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' to File cache in /home/user/cakephp-core/cakephp-2.4.6/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 325

[15-Mar-2014 19:47:46] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function error_get_last() in /home/user/cakephp-core/cakephp-2.4.6/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 911
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed my PHP version is 5.1, this is probably the issue, getting 5.5. Close please.

Comment: You can also delete the post if it's no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the app/tmp/ folder is writable by your web server user.